# Different logo for PreferenceScreen

Tags: android

I have two `PreferenceActivity` for my app and use a different icons and logo for them as follows:

```
  <activity android:name=".dashanalytics.DashAnalyticsPreferenceActivity" android:icon="@drawable/ic_dashanalytics" android:logo="@drawable/ic_dashanalytics" >
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".dashadsense.DashAdSensePreferenceActivity" android:logo="@drawable/ic_dashadsense"  android:icon="@drawable/ic_dashadsense" >
        </activity>
```

The problem is that the nested `PreferenceScreen` do not respect the logo settings defined for these settings. They inherit the logo setting defined at the `application` tag.

This results in nested preference screens to show up same icons. Is there a way to resolve thsi ?

Comment: It works fine. I just tried. Can you post your manifest file?

Comment: Did you try the nested preference screen? It works fine on the main activity

Comment: https://github.com/madhur/DashAnalytics/blob/develop/AndroidManifest.xml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this to manually set the home icon of the preference screen's window.

```
// Set the preference screen's home icon when the preference is clicked
final PreferenceScreen preferenceScreen = (PreferenceScreen) findPreference("my_screen");
preferenceScreen.setOnPreferenceClickListener(
        new Preference.OnPreferenceClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onPreferenceClick(Preference preference) {
                Window window = preferenceScreen.getDialog().getWindow();
                ImageView view = (ImageView) window.findViewById(android.R.id.home);
                if (view != null) {
                    view.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_my_icon);
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
```